# change frame source from other windows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 window in wpf application. There is a frame in window1. I want to change frame source from window2. can you help me?

for example:
window 1:

```
<frame x:name="frame1"/>
```

window2.cs :

```
private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
window1.frame1.source = new Uri("page1.xaml",UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the FieldModifier attribute of the Frame to `internal` or `public` or expose the Frame through a property in Window1:

```
<Frame x:Name="frame1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

You can then get a reference to Window1 and access the field or property using the `Application.Current.Windows` collection:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (window1 != null)
    {
        window1.frame1.Source = new Uri("page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Comment: @mm8 Thank you so much

Comment: @mm8 there's no type called "Window1" in WPF using net core 3.0, so what is the replacement?